# Why do I get invalid attribute error when I pass in a css selector?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

stackoverflow,

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
def get_element_from_list(root, item, index)
  @browser.elements(:css => root).each do |element|
    if element.present?
      return element.element(:css => item, :index => index)
    end
  end

  raise Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
end

get_element_from_list('div[class*=x-combo-list]', 'x-combo-list-item', index).click
```

gives me Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException: invalid attribute: :css

What I don't understand is if I simply do

```
@browser.elements(:css => 'div[class*=x-combo-list]').each do |element|
  if element.present?
    return element.element(:css => 'x-combo-list-item', :index => index)
  end
end
```

basically replacing root and item with the actual strings it works without error.

Comment: Have you checked that both root and item are not nil in whatever is calling this function?

Comment: Yeah, definitely not nil.

Comment: Are you really sure that your second bit of code with the strings directly inserted works? Seems a bit odd that there would be a "x-combo-list-item" tag (rather than class). I seem to get that exception whenever I try to combine the :css and :index locators, but I cannot figure out why from the code.

Comment: You are correct that it is not a tag but rather a class. Changing it to div[class=x-combo-list-item] does not change the error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a bug that prevents locating elements with the :css and :index locator - [Issue 241](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/241).

You can work around the issue by getting an element collection and then getting the element at the specific index:

```
return element.elements(:css => 'x-combo-list-item')[index]
```

(Note that I think this css-selector might be wrong. It is probably meant to be `.x-combo-list-item`.)

Alternatively, assuming that `x-combo-list-item` is actually the element's class, you could do:

```
return element.element(:class => 'x-combo-list-item', :index => index)
```

Comment: Okay, your index workaround fixed the issue. You are correct it is a class but I'm trying to keep this method generalized for different types of list we encounter, thus the use of css.